# APC UPS Shutting itself off after a few seconds

Tags: ups, apc-powerchute

I have an APC Back-UPS 600 UPS. When I turn it on with no load, the light blinks green while it emits a constant tone.  It then clicks and the light turns off, but the tone continues.  I can make the tone stop by long pressing the button, but I think it would go forever otherwise. What does this mean?  Is the unit shot?

Comment: How old is the battery?

Comment: Battery is likely gone from what you say. I have an APC UPS in the basement.  Otherwise my own APC is built like a tank and should last (battery aside) a very long time. Already over 10 years old and like new.

Comment: The unit is pretty new, but there was a storm that may have caused damage.

Comment: That is possible. I have mine on a separate circuit and the outside AC merely charges the battery. If you have any question, get it serviced by a local shop. There are not any user serviceable sections inside.

Comment: UPS batteries should be changed every 3 years or so. APC does sell replacement batteries you can install yourself.  https://www.apcbatterybackup.com/

Comment: This unit is about 3 months old.  I contacted APC support and they had no clue but are sending me a replacement.